# Maximal ideals in Boolean algebras; reference request

Tags: boolean-algebras, set-theory, reference-request

An old theorem of Pospisil asserts that for any infinite set $I$ the power-set algebra $\wp(I)$ has $\exp \exp |I|$ many maximal ideals containing the ideal of finite sets. This result is published in a rather obscure Czech journal but it seems it should be well-known and described in many textbooks/monographs. I would appreciate any references for that.

Also, I am interested in more general results, that is, what are the sufficient conditions for a given Boolean algebra $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \wp(I)$ with $\mbox{fin}(I)\subseteq \mathcal{A}$ to have $\exp \exp |I|$ many maximal ideals containing $\mbox{fin}(I)$.

Thank you.

Comment: Pospíšil's result is published in Annals of Mathematics 38 (1937), no. 4, 845­-846 (http://www.jstor.org/stable/1968840).

Comment: Thanks, I have found the same result in 
On bicompact spaces. Publ. Fac. Sci. Univ. Masaryk 270 (1939), 3-16.

Comment: May I ask why the downvote? The question was asked 9 years ago...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result on the number of maximal ideals can be found as Corollary 7.4. in the book  Comfort & Negrepontis "The Theory of Ultrafilters", 1974. A proof can also be found at PlanetMath [here](https://planetmath.org/NumberOfUltrafilters).

Answer (score 3):

I am sure this is in Koppelberg's Handbook of Boolean Algebras, though I have not checked (I will check later).
A proof of Pospisil's result is in [this survey-paper](http://www.hcm.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/geschke/papers/IndependentFamilies_03.pdf) of mine 
that will appear in RIMS Kokyuroku.

I am not sure I completely understand the second part of your question, though.
Are you asking for conditions when you have this many maximal ideals?
For example, it could happen that $\mathcal A$ is only of size $|I|$ and you have at most 
$2^{|I|}$ maximal ideals.

Comment: Thanks for this. By the way, do you know who was Pondiczery and what was his first name?

Comment: @Tomek http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_P._Boas,_Jr., http://at.yorku.ca/t/o/p/c/40.htm

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the obscure Czech journal, Pospíšil published his result in the *Annals of Mathematics*:

> Bedřich Pospíšil: *Remark on bicompact spaces*, Annals of Mathematics 38 (1937), no. 4, pp. 845–846, doi [10.2307/1968840](https://doi.org/10.2307/1968840).